# Convert figure from pylab into base64 without caching it

Tags: python, matplotlib, base64, figure

I'm ploting some images on python and I want to send them to a mySQL database.

For that, I'm currently saving my image and then opening and converting it to base64.

I would like to **avoid saving the image**. How can I do that?

My current python code for saving the image is presented below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     
plt.figure(1)                       # create figure
plot(t, x, 'r.-')                   # plot x values (red)
plot(t, y, 'g.-')                   # plot y values (green)
plot(t, z, 'b.-')                   # plot z values (blue)
legend(['x','y','z'])               # label the plotted lines
savefig("sample_test.jpeg")   # save figure
```

And the code that opens the image is:

```
img = open("sample_test.jpeg")
img_b64 = base64.b64encode(img .read())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this, where you'd save the image to a buffer and read it in again.

```
from io import BytesIO
buf = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf, format="png")
data = base64.b64encode(buf.getbuffer())
```

I'm no expert in databases, but maybe you want to convert to ascii as well,

```
data = data.decode("ascii")
```